# Why is the button not being shown in form?

Tags: python, html, css, django, file

I'm trying to develop a website for an online store and after I added my css files to the base.html file, everything is working fine,but an input button for update cart is not being shown properly although it was working fine before adding the css static file.What can I do? Can someone please help me with this?

My cart.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} 

{% block content %}
{% if empty %}
  <h1 class='text-center'>{{ empty_message }}</h1>
{% else %}
  <div class="container text-black py-5 text-center">
    <h1 class="display">MyShop Cart</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container-md">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c560c025cf.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="card shopping-cart">
          <div class="card-header bg-dark text-light">
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Shipping cart
              <a href="{% url 'myshop-home' %}" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm pull-right">Continue shopping</a>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
          </div>
          <!-- PRODUCT -->
          
            <div class="pb-5">
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 p-5 bg-white rounded shadow-sm mb-5">
                      <!-- Shopping cart table -->
                      <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th scope="col" class="border-0 bg-light">
                                <div class="p-2 px-3 text-uppercase">Product</div>
                              </th>
                              <th scope="col" class="border-0 bg-light">
                                <div class="py-2 text-uppercase">Price</div>
                              </th>
                              <th scope="col" class="border-0 bg-light">
                                <div class="py-2 text-uppercase">Quantity</div>
                              </th>
                              <th scope="col" class="border-0 bg-light">
                                <div class="py-2 text-uppercase">Remove</div>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          {% for item in cart.cartitem_set.all %}
                                          <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                              <th scope="row" class="border-0">
                                                <div class="p-2">
                                                  <img src="{{ item.product.image_url }}" alt="" width="70" class="img-fluid rounded shadow-sm">
                                                  <div class="ml-3 d-inline-block align-middle">
                                                    <h5 class="mb-0"> <a href="#" class="text-dark d-inline-block align-middle">{{ item.product.name }}</a>
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>
                                              </th>
                                              <td class="border-0 align-middle"><strong>${{ item.product.price }}</strong></td>
                                              <td class="border-0 align-middle"><strong>
                                                <div class="pull-center">
                                                  <div class="quantity">
                                                    <form method='Get' action="{% url 'add-to-cart' item.product.slug %}">
                                                      <input name="qty" type="number" step="1" min="1" value="{{ item.quantity }}" title="quantity" class="qty"size="4"/>
                                                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" value="Update Cart"/>
                                                    </form>  
                                                  </div>      
                                                </div>
                                                </strong></td>
                                              <td class="border-0 align-middle"><a href="{% url 'add-to-cart' item.product.slug %}?qty=0" class="text-dark"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </h5>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </th>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          {% endfor %}
          </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          <!-- END PRODUCT -->
              <!-- End -->
              <div class="row py-5 p-4 bg-white rounded shadow-sm">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="bg-light rounded-pill px-4 py-3 text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Coupon code</div>
                  <div class="p-4">
                    <p class="font-italic mb-4">If you have a coupon code, please enter it in the box below</p>
                    <div class="input-group mb-4 border rounded-pill p-2">
                      <input type="text" placeholder="Apply coupon" aria-describedby="button-addon3" class="form-control border-0">
                      <div class="input-group-append border-0">
                        <button id="button-addon3" type="button" class="btn btn-dark px-4 rounded-pill"><i class="fa fa-gift mr-2"></i>Apply coupon</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="bg-light rounded-pill px-4 py-3 text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Instructions for seller</div>
                  <div class="p-4">
                    <p class="font-italic mb-4">If you have some information for the seller you can leave them in the box below</p>
                    <textarea name="" cols="30" rows="2" class="form-control"></textarea>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                  <div class="bg-light rounded-pill px-4 py-3 text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Order summary </div>
                  <div class="p-4">
                    <p class="font-italic mb-4">Shipping and additional costs are calculated based on values you have entered.</p>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mb-4">
                      <li class="d-flex justify-content-between py-3 border-bottom"><strong class="text-muted">Order Subtotal </strong><strong>${{ cart.total }}</strong></li>
                      <li class="d-flex justify-content-between py-3 border-bottom"><strong class="text-muted">Shipping and handling</strong><strong>$10.00</strong></li>
                      <li class="d-flex justify-content-between py-3 border-bottom"><strong class="text-muted">Tax</strong><strong>$0.00</strong></li>
                      <li class="d-flex justify-content-between py-3 border-bottom"><strong class="text-muted">Total</strong>
                        <h5 class="font-weight-bold">${{ cart.total }}</h5>
                      </li>
                    </ul><a href="#" class="btn btn-dark rounded-pill py-2 btn-block">Proceed to checkout</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
             
  </div>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

My main.css file:

```
input[type=text]:focus {
  width: 10%;    
  border: 3px solid #555;
}

body {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  min-height: 100vh;
}


body { padding-top: 70px; }
```

Comment: Could you perhaps click edit, then scroll down and click `[<>]` snippet editor and add a [mcve] using only relevant HTML and CSS, i.e. RENDERED code. It is not likely a python, or django issue is it?

Comment: Use your browser's debugger, that's what it's for. You can edit the css inline (select the input element in the source pane, then look at the css rules).